# Xamarin HttpClient

Tags: android, xamarin.ios, xamarin.forms, androidhttpclient

I'm using Xamarin Forms to consume REST Api from NetFlix but i get this issue in Popup:
System.Net.WebException: Error: NameResolutionFailure

Why o get this error?

My Code:

```
private HttpClient client = new HttpClient();
    private List<Movie> movies;

    public async Task<List<Movie>> LocalizaFilmesPorAtor(string ator)
    {

        if (string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(ator))
        {
            return null;
        }
        else
        {
            string url = string.Format("http://netflixroulette.net/api/api.php?actor={0}", ator);
            var response = await client.GetAsync(url);

            if (response.StatusCode == HttpStatusCode.NotFound)
            {
                movies = new List<Movie>();
            } else
            {

                var content = await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
                var _movies = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<Movie>>(content);
                movies = new List<Movie>(_movies);
            }

            return movies;
        }
    }
```

In debug mode said the error is in this code

```
string url = string.Format("http://netflixroulette.net/api/api.php?actor={0}", ator);
            var response = await client.GetAsync(url);
```

He stops in there, the url recive the url + actor name but in next line the response stay null.

PS: I give Internet permission to my App in Manifest!

Comment: NameResolutionFailure usually means a DNS problem.  Have you verified that you can load that site from the device's browser?

Comment: When URL fails, check the URL in browser. sometimes it is on their side than your side. More reason to add error catch in your coding

Comment: In the android emulator I get this a lot, sometimes the network bridge doesn't come up properly.

Comment: Make sure the emulator has access to the internet opening the emulator browser and accessing any website (google.com par example).

Comment: I got it, thanks again!

Answer (score 0):

nuget packages: **Microsoft HTTP Client Libraries** and **Newtonsoft.Json**.

try this:

```
private HttpClient client = new HttpClient();
private List<Movie> movies;

public async Task<List<Movie>> LocalizaFilmesPorAtor(string ator)
{

    if (string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(ator))
    {
        return null;
    }
    else
    {
     var client = new HttpClient(); 
     client.BaseAddress = new Uri("http://netflixroulette.net/");
     HttpResponseMessage response = client.GetAsync("api/api.php?actor={0}", ator);
        if(response.IsSuccessStatusCode)
        {
         var json = response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync().Result;
         var _movies = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<Movie>>(json);
         movies = new List<Movie>(_movies);

        }
        else
        {

            movies = new List<Movie>();
        }

        return movies;
    }
}
```

PS: if **movies = new List(_movies)** not work, try foreach.

Comment: When giving an answer it is preferable to give [some explanation as to WHY your answer](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer) is the one.

Comment: Sorry i'm new here, next time i will do better.

Comment: You could actually do better right now.  Just below your post on the left side is an `edit` link. Don't be shy about editing to improve things around here. Cheers.

Comment: What is better/different with this solution?

Answer (score 0):

I had this issue too because my URL was malformed. Double check if your URL is correct with Postman/Browser.

Answer (score -1):

Why cant you try Refit?
Refit is a library heavily inspired by Square's Retrofit library, and it turns your REST API into a live interface

What you just need to do is:

1. Add Refit from Nuget Package
2. Create an Interface with any name
3. Import the Refit (Using Refit)

here is a sample code for the interface

```
public interface ISampleName
{

    [Get("api/api.php?actor={ator}")]
    async Task<List<Movie>> LocalizaFilmesPorAtor(string ator);
}
```

After that, then you can call it this way:

```
var SampleNameApi = RestService.For<ISampleName>("http://netflixroulette.net/");

var response= await SampleNameApi.LocalizaFilmesPorAtor("Sample");
```

I believe this will help you.

For More Information https://github.com/paulcbetts/refit